# is "if any" the same as "if existing"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms

Given this sentence:

> Its original manufacturer’s warranty, if any, still applies, with warranty details included in the item details.

Can I change “if any” in the above sentence to “if existing”?

> Its original manufacturer’s warranty, if existing, still applies, with warranty details included in the item details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, *in this sentence*, without changing the meaning in any substantial way. I would not recommend doing so, however, as "if any" flows better, while "if existing" sounds stilted. There will be other sentences in which such a substitution would change the meaning, however.

Comment: what "stilted" means? like not elegant?

Comment: so "if any" means "if there is any warranty"?

Comment: Stilted means awkwardly formal or precise. And yes, "if any" means "if there is any warranty" in this context.

Comment: Someone want to explain why they voted this answer down?